# Automatically crop and resize image to a specific size

Tags: php, image

I'm making a photo gallery for my website. This is a grid a miniatures (400 x 300px). When user click on the minitature, the image appears in his full size. The users can upload images but my problem is how crop and / or resize the image uploaded to create a miniature with a size of 400 x 300px **by keeping it proportionally** ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP resize image proportionally to a bigger size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14096065/php-resize-image-proportionally-to-a-bigger-size)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6440113/proportional-image-resizing

Comment: Is the user free to choose the aspect ratio or does the upload require a specific image size? Because shrinking the image proportionally requires an original size of i*400 x i*300. Otherwise there will be black bars.

Comment: @Waki Yes sorry I didn't see this question

Comment: @quickshiftin I've already searched before posting a question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I worked this out in few of my projects, This will work for you not test for all stuff. This will help you to come to better solution.

```
// RESIZE AN IMAGE PROPORTIONALLY AND CROP TO THE CENTER


function resize_and_crop($original_image_url, $thumb_image_url, $thumb_w, $thumb_h, $quality=75)
{
    // ACQUIRE THE ORIGINAL IMAGE: http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromjpeg.php
    $original = imagecreatefromjpeg($original_image_url);
    if (!$original) return FALSE;

    // GET ORIGINAL IMAGE DIMENSIONS
    list($original_w, $original_h) = getimagesize($original_image_url);

    // RESIZE IMAGE AND PRESERVE PROPORTIONS
    $thumb_w_resize = $thumb_w;
    $thumb_h_resize = $thumb_h;
    if ($original_w > $original_h)
    {
        $thumb_h_ratio  = $thumb_h / $original_h;
        $thumb_w_resize = (int)round($original_w * $thumb_h_ratio);
    }
    else
    {
        $thumb_w_ratio  = $thumb_w / $original_w;
        $thumb_h_resize = (int)round($original_h * $thumb_w_ratio);
    }
    if ($thumb_w_resize < $thumb_w)
    {
        $thumb_h_ratio  = $thumb_w / $thumb_w_resize;
        $thumb_h_resize = (int)round($thumb_h * $thumb_h_ratio);
        $thumb_w_resize = $thumb_w;
    }

    // CREATE THE PROPORTIONAL IMAGE RESOURCE
    $thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($thumb_w_resize, $thumb_h_resize);
    if (!imagecopyresampled($thumb, $original, 0,0,0,0, $thumb_w_resize, $thumb_h_resize, $original_w, $original_h)) return FALSE;

    // ACTIVATE THIS TO STORE THE INTERMEDIATE IMAGE
    // imagejpeg($thumb, 'RAY_temp_' . $thumb_w_resize . 'x' . $thumb_h_resize . '.jpg', 100);

    // CREATE THE CENTERED CROPPED IMAGE TO THE SPECIFIED DIMENSIONS
    $final = imagecreatetruecolor($thumb_w, $thumb_h);

    $thumb_w_offset = 0;
    $thumb_h_offset = 0;
    if ($thumb_w < $thumb_w_resize)
    {
        $thumb_w_offset = (int)round(($thumb_w_resize - $thumb_w) / 2);
    }
    else
    {
        $thumb_h_offset = (int)round(($thumb_h_resize - $thumb_h) / 2);
    }

    if (!imagecopy($final, $thumb, 0,0, $thumb_w_offset, $thumb_h_offset, $thumb_w_resize, $thumb_h_resize)) return FALSE;

    // STORE THE FINAL IMAGE - WILL OVERWRITE $thumb_image_url
    if (!imagejpeg($final, $thumb_image_url, $quality)) return FALSE;
    return TRUE;
}


// USE CASE
echo '<a target="_blank" href="orig_600x374.jpg">Original 600x374</a><br/>';

resize_and_crop('orig_600x374.jpg', 'temp_100x100.jpg', 100, 100);
echo '<a target="_blank" href="temp_100x100.jpg">100x100</a><br/>';

resize_and_crop('orig_600x374.jpg', 'temp_200x100.jpg', 200, 100);
echo '<a target="_blank" href="temp_200x100.jpg">200x100</a><br/>';

resize_and_crop('orig_600x374.jpg', 'temp_200x300.jpg', 200, 300);
echo '<a target="_blank" href="temp_200x300.jpg">200x300</a><br/>';
```

Comment: Hi , I've tried this solution but It only crop the image from the top and bottom, it can't really crop it from the right and left sides ? is there a solution for this ?